# Stop video from playing if not in browser view but not restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, video

I'm trying to add a header video to my site. Once this video has ended it will scroll to a section. I have managed to make this work except there is one issue. If the user does not want to watch the video and scroll past it down the site it will still take the user back to the section.

I was wondering is there a way of editing my code so that the end scroll does not work unless the video is on the users view?

```js
$('#headervideo').bind("ended", function(){ 
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#id4").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="headervideo" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="http://bluenodehosting.com/video/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<section id="id4">
1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
</section>
```

One solution I came up with was to pause the video if it's not in the users view. The issue with this is if the user does watch the video it will scroll down as planned. But it the user then scrolls backup over the video it will start again.

I don't want it to stat again?

**Below is my full code**

```js
$('#headervideo').bind("ended", function(){ 
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#id4").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    });
    
    
function isInView(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();           // absolute position of video element
  return !(rect.top > $(window).height() || rect.bottom < 0);   // visible?
}

$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  $( "#headervideo" ).each(function() {
    if (isInView($(this)[0])) {                    // visible?
      if ($(this)[0].paused) $(this)[0].play();    // play if not playing
    }
    else {
      if (!$(this)[0].paused) $(this)[0].pause();  // pause if not paused
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="headervideo" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="http://bluenodehosting.com/video/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


<section id="id4">
1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
function checkIfShouldScroll() {
  var $headerVid = $('#headervideo');
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < $headerVid.height() + $headerVid.offset().top) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#id4").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  }
}

$('#headervideo').on('ended', function(){
  checkIfShouldScroll();
});
```

This way checks if you should scroll after the video plays through entirely. So it'll continue to play when you scroll down. If you want to pause it when the user scrolls down and then play it again as they come back up the page, you'd have to couple it with some viewability detection, like you were trying before.

Using this example, you could remove your check `inView` and `$(document)` functions. It looks to see that the window has scrolled below the header video's height plus its offset from the top of the window, in case you make a top nav later or something.